# Selecting edge loops by angle threshold

Tags: modeling, scripting, edges

I'm currently trying to clean up a model, and I was wondering if it is possible to select all edge loops with an angle below a certain threshold. Obviously you can select **edges** by face angle by using the "*Select Sharp Edges*" option, but I'm thinking about selecting full edge loops so that when you dissolve them the topology doesn't take a hit.

Selecting edges within the threshold seems like  it could be done with:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.edges_select_sharp(sharpness=angleInRadians)
```

But I'm stuck at deselecting the edges that don't form a full loop; that being that the first edge connects to the last edge through a single vertex and vertices where the loop goes through don't have a valence higher than 4 or it would create an n-gon when dissolved.